# Property name same as non anonymous function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coding-style

I'd like to use non anonymous functions for a better debugging purpose and encountered the following question.

When I have a function returning an object of methods (like in angularjs factories), is it bad style to name the returned property and the function the same?

Like here:

```
angular
    .module('myModule', [])
    .factory('foobar', foobar);

function foobar() {
    return {
        foo: function foo() {console.log('foo')},     //Is this ok
        bar: function barFunc() {console.log('bar')}  //Or this way better
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't wan't anonymous functions, why not declare them before the `return` statement?

Comment: this doesn't change the question... It will still be `return {foo: foo}`. The whole question is about good and bad javascript style.

Comment: Why would it be bad style?

Comment: Concerning debugging issues perhaps... I don't know, just asking. After watching 'Javascript the good parts', I am curious about anything concerning style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a question of style, and doesn't have a definitive answer. There is surely **nothing wrong** with naming the function expression the same as the property.

However, you are aiming for a better debugging experience. So you should ask yourself: "*What name helps me best to identify the function in my code by its name?*". Whether that might be `foo`, `fooFunc`, `foobar_foo` (including the module name) or anything else, you will have to decide yourself.

Answer (score 1):

both options are totally fine - the only difference you will get is that while debugging you'll see function's name instead of `anonymous function` which is REALLY useful.

so to sum it up - I would advise you to name them, but the naming is totally up to you :-)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it would be like so:

```
function foobar() {
  return {
    foo() { console.log('foo') }
  };
}
```

Comment: Nice approach, but I do have multiple properties returned.